# Google maps error Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token )

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm using buddy press and added a google maps on the profile. Sometimes the maps displays correctly and sometimes it doesn't.

I checked "inspect element" on the page where the maps doesn't show up and get a "Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token) Can anyone help me solve the missing map problem?

Here's the php code for reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
if (jQuery('#member-map').length != 0) {

    function a_page_maps() {

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(26.745610382199022, 2.63671875);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("member-map"), myOptions);

        var gmarkers = [];

        function createMarker(latlng,html,url,icon) {

            var contentString = html;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: icon
            });

            gmarkers.push(marker);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                infowindow.close(map,marker);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                window.location = url;
            });

        }
        <?php
        foreach ($placel as $place) {
        if(get_post_meta($place, 'article_location', true) <> "") {
        ?>
var image = '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/red-pushpin.png';
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo get_post_meta($place, 'article_location_latlon', true); ?>);
            var html = "<h5><?php echo get_post_meta($place, 'article_location', true); ?></h5><p class='popup'><em>&darr; Click to see articles about this location &darr;</em></p>";
            var url = '<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/locations/?location=<?php echo urlencode(get_post_meta($place, 'article_location', true)); ?>';

            var marker = createMarker(point,html,url,image);

        <?php
        }
        }
        ?>

        <?php
        foreach ($placegol as $placego) {
        if(get_post_meta($placego, 'article_location', true) <> "") {
        ?>

            var image = '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/grn-pushpin.png';
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo get_post_meta($placego, 'article_location_latlon', true); ?>);
            var html = "<h5><?php echo get_post_meta($placego, 'article_location', true); ?></h5><p class='popup'><em>&darr; Click to see articles about this location &darr;</em></p>";
            var url = '<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/locations/?location=<?php echo urlencode(get_post_meta($placego, 'article_location', true)); ?>';

            var marker = createMarker(point,html,url,image);
        <?php
        }
        }
        ?>
    }
        a_page_maps();   
    }    
});
</script>
```

Comment: The error message you get means you are missing a single `)` in your code. Use debugging tools like Firebug (for FF) or the built-in Dev Tools (Chrome & Safari), and they will point you to the exact line where the character is missing! Usually you will have a line number next to each syntax error that you can click and will see and fix the error in not time. See [this for example](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)

Comment: It might make sense to add the resultant javascript code to the question as well - that should be easier to spot a javascript error in than the php.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
```

should be

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

The nested function is a bad idea.  And what  lnrbob said, post the actual generated javascript, not the PHP code.